# Github Unable to write new index file

Tags: windows-10, git, github

When committing my code to GitHub, I get the following error.

```
GitHub.IO.ProcessException: fatal: Unable to write new index file
```

Here is my log:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7b65cf3xzio3ya/GitHubLog.txt?dl=0

I got almost 900GB free diskspace. Windows 10.

Comment: Have you asked their support? Does this only happen with the Desktop app or also via regular command line?

Comment: Yes I already sent it to their support 2 days ago - and it happens both with VScode, with desktop app (github) and with command line.  Its really annoying, been working for weeks, then 2 days ago I `npm install angular` and thats when it went bad.

Comment: What OS are you on? Please [edit] your post and add a tag.